# Facebook Like count for multi URLs using javascript and user control

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, user-controls, repeater

I have a `javascript` method that get number of facebook likes for given URL. 
I put this function in user control and call this control in **repeater** for multi item.
When I run the page, I get the number of likes for the first item in the repeater only.
How can I solve this?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FacebookNoOfLikes.ascx.cs" Inherits="TELiveSports.FrontEnd.UserControls.FacebookNoOfLikes" %>
<script type="text/javascript">

function fetchLikeCount(url) {

   // alert(url);
    return $.Deferred(function (defer) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?callback=callback',
            data: {
                query: 'SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="' + url + '"',
                format: 'JSON'
            }
        }).then(function (res) {
            try {
                var count = res[0].like_count;
                defer.resolve(count);
            } catch (e) {
                reject();
            }
        }, reject);
        function reject() {
            defer.reject('-');
        };
    }).promise();
}

function GetPageFaceLikes(controlName) {

    fetchLikeCount(document.getElementById(controlName).value).always(function (res) {
        $("#res").text(res);
    });
}
```

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="lbl_URL" Value='<%#Eval("ShareItemURL") %>' />
<div id="res">
<script type="text/javascript">

function pageLoad(){
        GetPageFaceLikes('<%= lbl_URL.ClientID %>')
    };

 </script>

</div>
```

Comment: Help please any help

Comment: Please i need solution from experts